# Boolean Set To True Does Not Pass

Tags: java, boolean

Me and my team of four are developing a game in an Advanced Java Object-Oriented Programming class called "Chemistry Escape Room". Our program has items that are collected in a JToolBar which keeps the items through every class with a Toolbar.java class. We use booleans from Items.java which is set to false, and then once a JButton is clicked the booleans are set to true then is passed to the Toolbar.java class where all the items are stored in a JToolbar.

The problem is is that once the items are set to true they don't seem to stay true. I set the if statement to detect if the boolean is false and THEN the item/button will show up in the JToolBar.

**Items.java:**

```
public class Items extends JFrame { 
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
static boolean flaskpickup = false;
static boolean jugpickup = false;
static boolean bookpickup = false;
static boolean gflaskpickup = false;
static boolean paperpickup = false;
static boolean keypickup = false;
static int test;

public static Component btnFlask()
{


    JButton btnFlask = new JButton();
    btnFlask.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryTeachersDesk.class.getResource("/Images/flask_blue.png")));
    btnFlask.setBounds(607, 351, 141, 103);
    btnFlask.setOpaque(false);
    btnFlask.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnFlask.setBorderPainted(false);


    btnFlask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnFlask.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(),
                    "It's a Flask of Hyrdrogen, still cold and liquified. Maybe you can combine this with something.",
                    "Flask of Hydrogen",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            flaskpickup = true;
            test = 1;
        }
    });

    //Toolbar.bar();
    return btnFlask;
}

public static Component btnJug()
{
    JButton btnJug = new JButton();
    btnJug.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryDoor.class.getResource("/Images/waterjug1.png")));
    btnJug.setBounds(219, 409, 85, 87);
    btnJug.setOpaque(false);
    btnJug.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnJug.setBorderPainted(false);


    btnJug.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnJug.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(),
                    "This water is cold and fresh, maybe you should add it to something.",
                    "Jug of Water",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            jugpickup = true;
        }
    });

    return btnJug;
}

public static Component btnBook() {
    JButton btnBook = new JButton();
    btnBook.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryRoom.class.getResource("/Images/textbook.png")));
    //btnBook.setOpaque(false);
    btnBook.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnBook.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnBook.setBounds(505, 258, 87, 65);

    btnBook.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnBook.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(),
                    "By the cover, it seems this is a textbook for chemistry. Maybe it contains the answers to getting out of this room.",
                    "Chemistry Textbook",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            bookpickup = true;
        }
    });


    return btnBook;
}

public static Component btnGreenFlask() {
    JButton btngFlask = new JButton();
    btngFlask.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btngFlask.setBorderPainted(false);
    btngFlask.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryRoom.class.getResource("/Images/flask.png")));
    btngFlask.setBounds(265, 265, 58, 58);

    btngFlask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btngFlask.setVisible(false);
            //btnToolFlask.setVisible(true);
            gflaskpickup = true;
        }
    });

    return btngFlask;

}

public static Component Paper() {
    JButton btnPaper = new JButton();
    btnPaper.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnPaper.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnPaper.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryDoor.class.getResource("/Images/paper1.png")));
    btnPaper.setBounds(513, 465, 99, 50);

    btnPaper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnPaper.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "This slip of paper says that to mix chemical one with chemical two",
                    "Cheet Sheet",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            paperpickup = true;

        }
    });
    return btnPaper;
}

public static Component btnKey() {
    JButton btnKey = new JButton();
    btnKey.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryDoor.class.getResource("/Images/key.png")));
    btnKey.setBounds(32, 469, 67, 50);
    btnKey.setOpaque(false);
    btnKey.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnKey.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    btnKey.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnKey.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                    "This key looks like it unlocks something you need.",
                    "Key",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            //btnKey_1.setVisible(true);
            keypickup = true;
        }
    });

    return btnKey;
}
```

}

**Toolbar.java:**

```
public class Toolbar {

public static Component bar() 
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    toolBar.setBackground(Color.RED);
    toolBar.setBounds(0, 553, 782, 50);


    if(Items.flaskpickup == true)
    {
        JButton btnHydrogen = new JButton("Hydrogen");
        btnHydrogen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryTeachersDesk.class.getResource("/Images/flask_small.png")));
        btnHydrogen.setVisible(true);
        toolBar.add(btnHydrogen);
        return btnHydrogen;
    }

    return panel.add(toolBar);
}
```

}

**ChemistryTeachersDesk.java:** *(Shows the buttons/items and toolbar)*

```
    //Regular Buttons
    if(Items.flaskpickup == false) {
        contentPane.add(Items.btnFlask());
    }

    contentPane.add(Toolbar.bar());
```

Our full code: https://github.com/Mr-El/CIS319-T6-EscapeRoom

Executable: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-wvAphtOemebTRlZThlY19Rb00

Comment: your team should use debuger

Comment: Way too much code. See [mcve]

Comment: Would not be it easier to add all buttons, and use the `enabled` property to gray it out, if cannot be used at the moment?

Comment: You might also think of a better design. Keeping state in static variables (and in a UI component) doesn't seem like good design. Your variables `jugPickup` etc. seem to represent the player's inventory so you might want to design that accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I'll keep that in mind and tell my teammates about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that You create all UI components on startup of application and It's not refreshed after application changes static flags. 
This code will be executed only once on startup:

```
 if(Items.flaskpickup == true)
    {
        JButton btnHydrogen = new JButton("Hydrogen");
        btnHydrogen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChemistryTeachersDesk.class.getResource("/Images/flask_small.png")));
        btnHydrogen.setVisible(true);
        toolBar.add(btnHydrogen);
        return btnHydrogen;
    }
```

Comment: So what can I do other than static flags?

Comment: btnHydrogen.setVisible(true); in actionListeners, instedad of flaskpickup = true;

Comment: But it is in seperate classes.